# What's wrong with my cycas?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, leaves

I have some questions: [image: cycas]

1. What are these, new leaves?(red circle)
2. What is this?(white circle)
3. And my cycas leaves are turning yellow (yellow circle). What is the matter? Is my cycas dying?(It's old and some of it's new leaves are turning yellow)

Comment: You can cut all the old leaves off. Some neighbors do that  This year the global warming freeze killed old leaves ( fronds) in E TX ,so I am in process of removing all leaves on 20 plants.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, new leaves. They appear in the centre of the plant, pushing the older leaves to the outside, where they get older and eventually die off to be replaced by more leaves in the centre.

2 & 3 Cycas leaves are pretty tough and not likely to be attacked by pests and diseases; however if weakened by overwatering they become vulnerable to many of the insects and diseases we see on softer plants. The only way to know if insects are present is to examine the leaves very carefully under magnification. If you don't see anything it is probably just the plant reorganizing its internal chemistry, moving nutrient from older leaves to support new growth. At the time of new leaf production, expect to see stealing from older leaves.